# My code in R using REGEX doesn't work why and how to fix?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to clean out the text of the retailers which have dashes in them.

I'm new to R and programming itself, so please help me out here. I know a bit of REGEX in general.

```
mydata = read.csv("test4+.csv", header = TRUE)
mydata[,c("Store.Name")]

filenames <- c( "test4+.csv", "test4+.csv" )

for( f in filenames ){
  z <- readLines(f)
  a <- gsub("([S|s]potlight)\\s+(.*)", "\\1 - \\2", z)
  b <- gsub("([W|w]oolworths)\\s*(.*)", "\\1 - \\2", z)
  c <- gsub("([B|b]ig)(W)\\s*-*\\s*(.*)", "\\1 \\2 - \\3", z)

  cat(a, file=f, sep="\n")
  cat(b, file=f, sep="\n")
  cat(c, file=f, sep="\n")}


for( f in filenames ){ 
   cat(readLines(f), sep="\n")
}
```

Where col1 should look like col2:

```
col1                                     col2
woolworths abc                     woolworths - abc
woolworths bcd bce                 woolworths - bcd bce
spotlight blah blah (blah)         spotlight - blah blah (blah)
BigW act                           Big W - act
external                           external
```

Comment: Should look like column 1 or 2? What do you have and what do you expect?

Comment: it should look like column 2

Comment: So only the first ` ` (space) should be replaced by ` - ` (space-dash-space), right?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder yes sir

Comment: just do `sub("\\s"," - ",mydata$col1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out:

```
a <- gsub("^(?:.*?)(\\s+)(?:.+)$", " - ", z)
```

And so on for the others.

I'll be quite frank with you, I have never used regex in `r` before, or `gsub`, but this is the closest approximation I have.

Comment: is there a way to apply them in different lines, such that i implement one idea then another then another. seperately but not altogether?

Comment: @user9525789 Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do the exact same `gsub()` method for `b <- gsub(...)` and for `c`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 gsub('([[:punct:]])|\\s+',' - ',data$column) #replace white space with " - "
```